# How to access a field from an extended user in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to figure out how to display the userRating field from the extended user model below in a template, but nothing is showing up.

**Model:**

```
class userProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    USER_RATING_CHOICES = (("1 star", "1 Star(s)"), ("2 star", "2 Star(s)"), ("3 star", "3 Star(s)"), ("4 star", "4 Star(s)"), ("5 star", "5 Star(s)"))        
    userRating = models.CharField("User rating", max_length=6, choices=USER_RATING_CHOICES, default="1 star")

class partListing(models.Model):
    partName = models.CharField("Name", max_length=200)
    datePublished = models.DateTimeField("Date published")
    postedBy = models.ForeignKey(User)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.partName
```

**View:**

```
def browse(request):
    partListingTitle = partListing.objects.filter(partName__startswith='2010')
    # Note: the startswith query here is just for testing
    return render_to_response("partmanager/browse.html",
                             {'partListingTitle' : partListingTitle},
                             context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

What I'm trying to do is have something like `User rating: 3 stars` in my template. I managed to get the postedBy field to work, but I just can't get userRating to display a rating.

Comment: You have posted everything but the very point of your problem - what's the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this: Add a `related_name` attribute to the `OneToOneField` and then reverse access it using the `.` accessor.

```
class userProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    USER_RATING_CHOICES = (("1 star", "1 Star(s)"), ("2 star", "2 Star(s)"), ("3 star", "3 Star(s)"), ("4 star", "4 Star(s)"), ("5 star", "5 Star(s)"))        
    userRating = models.CharField("User rating", max_length=6, choices=USER_RATING_CHOICES, default="1 star")
```

and then,

```
{% for listing in partListingTitle %}
    {{listing.postedBy.profile.userRating}}
{% endfor %}
```